# visualsvn server error "no such packed revision"

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Sudden freeze while using svn(client : tortoisesvn, server : visualsvn). So I checked the error message and found

"Can't get author of r138: No such packed revision 138 
(160006) APR does not understand this error code 
192.168.0.1"

Is there any reason why this error occurs or how can prevent it?

Comment: What VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN versions do you use? What's in the logs? https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/

Comment: Note that you can contact support@visualsvn.com if you still need assistance with this issue.